# How to fix "Error: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable"?

Tags: angular, loopbackjs

I'm using angular material table in that pagination is not working only in server but working fine in local. In server when I'll open the page which contains the table, the data is pushed in the table but the pagination is not working and error is popup

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.
> You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>     at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
>     at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub
> (mergeMap.js:74)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext
> (mergeMap.js:68)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next
> (mergeMap.js:51)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
> (Subscriber.js:53)
>     at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:5)
>     at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
> (Observable.js:43)
>     at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
> (Observable.js:29)
>     at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call
> (mergeMap.js:29)
> ```

Component.ts

```
getCustomerinfoList(): void {
    this.adminService.getCustomerinfoList(this.componentName, this.selectedCustomer.customer_id)
      .subscribe(customerlist => {
        let c_rates = customerlist[0][0].customer_routes;
        this.customers = customerlist;
        this.cust_specificData = c_rates ? JSON.parse(c_rates) : [];
        this.cInfo_dataSource.data = this.cust_specificData
        this.cInfo_dataSource.paginator = this.Routepaginator;
        this.cInfo_dataSource.sort = this.Routesort;
      }
  }
```

service.ts

```
getCustomerinfoList(actionComponentName: String, customerid: number) {
    const url = `${this.baseURL + actionComponentName}/getCustomerRateAccessories?customer_id=${customerid}&access_token=${this.authService.getAuthToken()}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url, this.httpOptions)
  }
```

Interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()

export class loadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: any, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let loadingContainer: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('bg-pre-loader').item(0) as HTMLElement

    loadingContainer.style.display = 'flex';

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          loadingContainer.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }), catchError((err) => {
        loadingContainer.style.display = 'none';
        return Observable.throw(err);
      })
    )
  }
}
```

I expect the data should push in table and the data should able to paginate

note:
this code work fine in local,
only in server it's not working as expected

Comment: the error is in mergeMap. you used mergeMap somewhere that is not working properly. here in this code sample I don't find you are using mergeMa

Comment: Check the `network` tab of the console. The response for the HTTP request may be invalid.

Comment: actually i got it working in local but in server it's not working only error poping i dont know where i had mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually error is in material table paginator it's got resolved when it's removed

thanks everyone